# Change the space between words only in section titles

Tags: spacing

In a section title the spacing of the words seems long to me although I get no warning by LaTeX for underful/overful boxes. How can I change the space between the words, but only in the titles of the sections?

Comment: Could you give an example of a sectioning header that generates warnings about overfull or underfull boxes? Also, which document class do you use?

Comment: @Mico I use article. I don't know about the example you ask though :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you want is to change the justification of the material in section-level headers from "full" (the default) to "ragged-right", i.e., no justification at all.

This may be achieved by providing the following instructions in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\raggedright}
```

A side-effect of `\raggedright` is that no discretionary hyphenation is performed in its scope. That's usually a desirable setting for the material in sectioning headers. If, however, you do wish to permit hyphenation, I suggest you further load the `ragged2e` package and replace `\sectionfont{\raggedright}` with `\sectionfont{\RaggedRight}`.

Answer (score -1):

use `\begin{flushleft}` before `\section` and `\end{flushleft}`